# P-Values from Robust Linear Mixed Models?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, inference, p-value, robust

I'm running a study which is is investigating how different types of smiles (two levels) are processed in different situational contexts (three levels).

I currently have a robust linear mixed model, with random intercepts and random slopes for both the participant and identity (i.e. the actor expressing the smile) as specified below:

```
rho.b <- list(chgDefaults(smoothPsi, k = 5.14), chgDefaults(smoothPsi, k = 5.14))

SupModRobust <- 
rlmer(Response ~ smileType*contextCat + (1 + smileType | Participant.Private.ID) + (1 + smileType | identity), data = SuperiorityData, method = "DASvar", rho.b = rho.b, rho.sigma.b = rho.b)
```

I can use the summary function to get the output of my robust model. However, if possible, I want to see inferential statistics (e.g. effect size and p-values) for the main and interaction effects. if I had a normal LMM, I would access these by using the anova function, like below:

```
anova(SupMod)
```

Which gives me output looking like this:

[image]

However, the anova function doesn't work on robust lmm model objects. Therefore, I was wondering whether there was any way of accessing equivalent statistics for the robust lmm?

Thank you!

Comment: How many observations do you have?  It may be that you can use a bootstrap approach, with some care in designing it due to the nature of your model, to get p-values...

Comment: @jbowman For this model, the dataset has 2040 observations (85 participants x 24 trials). However, I also have another larger dataset with exactly the same structure, but more observations (e.g. 85 participants x 36 trials) because I have removed one level of smile type

Comment: If you have two levels of smile type, how do you remove one?

Comment: @jbowman I actually had three levels, but I removed one to focus on two levels for this analysis. Apologies about not being more clear